# Problem with Bayes Theorem exercise

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

In a certain country, there are two types of job, good and bad, and two possible levels of
educational attainment, high and low. Everyone in this country is a member of one of two ethnic
groups, R and S. The probability of getting a good job if you have high education is 0.6; the
probability of getting a good job if you have low education is 0.3. Among the R group the
probability of getting high education is 0.2 and among the S group it is 0.5. How are the
members of the R and S groups distributed across good and bad jobs? If two-thirds of the
population belongs to the R group, what proportion of the population has a good job?